# Can I re-assign the scsi letter for virtual floppy?

Tags: redhat, storage-area-network, scsi, lun

Having issues with oracle starting up in our cluster environment due to disks not lining up properly. For example, on the problematic host, I see the following.

```
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  AMI      Virtual CDROM    1.00  /dev/sr0
[2:0:0:0]    disk    AMI      Virtual Floppy   1.00  /dev/sdc
```

My LUN from the SAN starts at /dev/sdd. On the server that works, I have the following:

```
[3:0:0:0]    disk    AMI      Virtual Floppy   1.00  /dev/sdt
```

So its LUN starts at /dev/sdc. How can I force the "Virtual Floppy" to give up `/dev/sdc` so my LUN can take it over?!

Comment: What kind of virtual is this virtual floppy?

Comment: beats the heck out of me. im thinking it has to do w/ the iLOM device. There isn't a floppy device on this server, just a DVD rom and 4 disks.

Comment: Do you need the virtual floppy? You can always remove it if not required.

Comment: Nope so how do i remove it. That would solve my issue.

Comment: full specs of server first please

Comment: Sun x4200 four scsi hard disk wirh a dvd drive.

Comment: oh balls, no idea with those sorry - never been a Sun guy

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the SCSI Device block device presentation isn't deterministic and never will be.

You must derive a unique identifier for that device and then create a UDEV rule that will create a persistent symlink which will always point to your virtual floppy, no matter what the scan order is.

See http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Trivial Example:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-assign-static-names-to-scsi-devices.html